# How to create a single MongoDB Container in Kubernates Cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am running a Kubernates Cluster in GCP. Each one of my clients/customer will need their own Kubernates Cluster.

Each Cluster/client needs to have their own database. What is the best way to go about this? I would like each cluster to have a MongoDB service so every pod in the cluster can communicate with the DB, but what is the correct way to do this? Create a pod running MongoDb with persistent storage on the node?

Create a replica set of mongoDB pods inside the cluster?

Have a single large MongoDB that each client's cluster can communicate with?

Answer (score 0):

For running database service such as Mongodb, I would recommend to use [Stateful Sets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/).

> StatefulSets are intended to be used with stateful applications and
>   distributed systems.

You can follow this nice [tutorial](https://medium.com/devopslinks/scaling-mongodb-on-kubernetes-32e446c16b82) to run stateful set Mongodb service on GKE and also it will be helpful to understand components, or you can use easily [mongodb-replicaset helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset) on each of your cluster.